# firebase authentication の情報をBigqueryに流し込めず困っています。

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

解析のために認証情報を取り扱うために使っているfirebaseのauthenticationの認証情報をBigQueryに流し込みたいと考えているのですが、うまくいっておりません。

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?authuser=0
に書かれているようにBigQueryとfirebaseをリンクしてみたのですが、authenticationはどうやら対応していないようでデータが流し込めません。
どうしたら良いでしょうか。初心者の質問で恐縮ですがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/129199

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/keito5656/firebase-authentication-to-bigquery-export

こちらを使うとできます。試してみてください。

Comment: SOではリンクのみの回答は推奨されておりません。（リンク切れになってしまった場合にこの回答が意味を成さなくなるからです。）せめてどういったものか説明や使い方のサンプルを記載してください。詳しくは[良い回答を書くには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)の「リンクの文脈を提示する」をご覧ください。